# unable include google api php client library (google-api-php-clientsrc/Google/autoload.php) in my php file

Tags: php, api, google-api-php-client

I want test google plus api php client on my localhost machine, but it not working like they said. Can you guide me what to do?

require_once realpath(dirname(**FILE**) . 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php');

Here the errors:
Warning: require_once(D:\xampp\htdocs\google_api): failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\xampp\htdocs\google_api\login_with_gp.php on line 4

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\google_api\login_with_gp.php on line 4

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: I am not allowed to post a image yet.

Comment: Link to one then. Or better yet, describe your problem in text; images can't be searched.

Comment: -If you have api folder and your php script in the same directory than use this.
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php";

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to have PHP installed in the localhost and the Apache server on. The files are in the right place, so it should work.